# Formatting classic ASP in an email

Tags: asp-classic

Can anyone tell me how i would format the following ASP line for an email with bold

```
email_body = email_body & "Full Name: " & fullname & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
```

I also tried:

```
email_body = email_body & "<b>Full Name:</b> " & fullname & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
```

But it didn't work, just showed the tags

The email just showed the bold tags

Sorry the format I want is
**Full Name:** John Smith 
And the ASP code is:

`email_body = email_body & "Full Name: " & fullname & vbcrlf & vbcrlf <br />`
 I tried adding the Bold tags around the Full name, but it didn't format it just showed the actual tags

Comment: can you post what is the output and what you want?

Comment: which mail component are you using ?

Comment: does your fullname variable really has the name? or is it null or some other value

Answer (score 1):

In order to have bold or other text formatting in an email, you have to make sure that the email is sent as HTML and not plain text. In your case it seems to be sent as plain text. Here are the ways to do it with the common mail components (some code copied from respective documentations):

**CDO**

```
objMessage.HTMLBody = "<h1>This is some sample message html.</h1>"
```

(the property is HTMLBody, not simply Body). Source: http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm

**ASPEmail**

Add:

```
Mail.IsHTML = True
```

Source: http://www.aspemail.com/manual_02.html

**JMail**

Add:

```
JMail.ContentType = "text/html"
```

Source: http://www.aspwebpro.com/aspscripts/email/jmail.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
Set Mail = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")
Mail.from = "me@me.com"  
Mail.to =  "me@me.com"
Mail.subject = "To Me"
sBody = "<h1>blah blah</h1>"
Mail.bodyFormat = CdoBodyFormatHTML
Mail.body = sBody
Mail.send
```